# PDT with Recurring Payments when trial price is 0

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am integrating Recurring Payments Button of PayPal Payments Standard. I want it to work so that when customer returns to my website, he sees appropriate message: "Thank you! You subscription id is: ..."

I have configured both PDT and IPN.
If I pass some trial price, both PDT and IPN work perfectly.
But if I pass 0 as trial price, then IPN works as expected, but PDT does not pass any variables. Customer is redirected back automatically, but neither GET nor POST parameters are passed. So I do not know his subscription ID and cannot display it until IPN message has arrived.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had one another question: [PDT with Recurring Payments when trial price is 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574008/pdt-with-recurring-payments-when-trial-price-is-0).

Based on Andrew Angell's advice I started to use Express Checkout.
It seems that Express Checkout does not have any regional restictions compared to PayPal Payments Standard.